# velocity of the center of mass frame and colliding particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames

Let's say two electrons undergo elastic collision. 'u' is the speed of the CM frame in the lab. My question is: Does it mean that the speed of the two electrons in CM frame is also 'u'?

My attempt: Using speed of Center of mass formula

$$ u = (m*v1 + m*v2) /  2*m $$

and since v1 = v2, then the speed of both electrons should be 'u'. Does this seem right?

And I think if I were to analyze the situation in lab frame, the speed of one of the moving electrons should be '2u', but I do not seem to be able to show it mathematically. Any help would be great.

Comment: Why $v_1=v_2$? If so, how could they possibly collide?

Comment: Why cannot they collide if they have same speed?

Comment: If they are speeds but not velocities, then you shouldn't use them in the way as your CM velocity equation

Comment: Since this is a one dimensional motion (at least before collision), does it matter if I use speed instead of velocity in the formula?

Comment: You mus use velocities, not speeds.

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass speed is
$$|v|=\left|\frac{m_1v_1+m_2v_2}{m_1+m_2}\right|$$
where $v_1$, $v_2$ are velocities.

It is different from
$$\frac{m_1|v_1|+m_2|v_2|}{m_1+m_2}$$